# If this is how you disable an element with jQuery, how do you re-enable it?

Tags: jquery

How do you re-enable an element after disabling it this way?

```
$("#foo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#foo').removeAttr('disabled');
```

and this as well:

```
$('#foo').attr('disabled', '');
```

Comment: `disabled` is a boolean, so why would you do the second?

Comment: Oh, do you mean when setting the element as disabled?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using a recent version of jQuery (1.6+), a more appropriate way of toggling the `disabled` attribute is using `.prop()`:

```
$("#foo").prop("disabled", true);
$("#foo").prop("disabled", false);
```

See [jQuery API documentation for .prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo').removeAttr('disabled');
```

OR you can set attr to ""

```
$('#foo').attr('disabled', '');
```